# Elasticsearch: use distance on dense vectors in relevance score (at query time)

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch to combine different things:
- search in text
- score based on dense vector (cosine similarity)

I use a query with `function_score`. The first part is the search in the text (giving a score) and THEN a script is applied to compute cosine similarity.

My problem is that the cosine similarity is not computed during the query phase and my search in the text act as a pre-filter. I will always obtain results linked with the text search even if the cosine similarity is better.

This is the standard behavior of `function_score` according the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html):

> The function_score allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query. This can be useful if, for example, a score function is computationally expensive and it is sufficient to compute the score on a filtered set of documents.

I would like to compute the cosine similarity at query time and this score will be combined with the text search (with as much importance).

Thanks !

You will find a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/thomas-chauvet/0a8317296800ecd3a92cb926e260fe7d) describing the problem with a "real" example.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I also posted it on the elastic forum. You will find an answer: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-distance-on-dense-vectors-in-relevance-score-at-query-time/217012/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-distance-on-dense-vectors-in-relevance-score-at-query-time/217012/2).

The solution is to use the [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause within a boolean query.

It will give something like:

```sh
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should" : [
          {
            "match": {
                "my_text": {
                    "query": "abc"
                }
            }
          },
          {
            "script_score" : {
              "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
              "script" : {
                "source": "50 * cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['my_vector']) + 1.0",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": [0, 0, 1]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }  
  }
}
```

It will combine scores from `my_text` and the `script_score` part. Final score will be the sum of the two.